# Generate JSON from utterance for LUIS

Tags: json, dataset, bots, azure-language-understanding

Is there anyway to take the Endpoint Utterance Log and use it to generate the JSON files needed to train your LUIS app using datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an example is on the LUIS-samples repository -
 https://github.com/Microsoft/LUIS-Samples/tree/master/examples/demo-upload-example-utterances